# Process a Either Reply [Maybe ByteString] into a [Maybe Text]

Tags: haskell, option-type, either

The following code runs a `mget` command with Hedis, and return the result as a `[Maybe BS.ByteString]`:

```hs
-- | Text to ByteString
tbs :: Text -> BS.ByteString
tbs = BS.pack . T.unpack


-- | ByteString to Text
bst :: BS.ByteString -> Text
bst = T.pack . BS.unpack


mgetRedis :: Redis.Connection -> [Text] -> IO [Maybe BS.ByteString]
mgetRedis connection keys =
    runRedis connection action
    where
        action = do

            result <- Redis.mget $ tbs <$> keys
            -- `result` is of type `Either Reply [Maybe BS.ByteString]`

            case result of
                Right values -> pure values
                _            -> pure []
```

First of all, I find this code quite messy and was wondering if there was any way to make it cleaner.

Second, I'd like `mgetRedis` to return a `[Maybe Text]` instead, using the `bst` helper written above. I can't do `pure $ bst <$> values` because there are two levels of unpacking here: first, the `Maybe` and then the `List`. Is there any way that this function could return the desired type without drowning in a sea of nested `case` statements?

Comment: `T.pack . BS.unpack` is almost certainly bad idea. Not only it's slow (because of the intermediate list, though the compiler might fuse that away), it also disregards any encoding issues. The `text` package offers [dedicated encoders](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html) that make this explicit. Also I find it dubious to return an empty list if the request has failed (?).

Comment: thanks for pointing the dedicated encoders — for the empty list, I agree, the alternative being, carrying the `Either` all the way down to the business logic code where the response will be processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about is essentially how to `fmap` arbitrarily deep into a stack of functors. That can easily be done by composing `fmap`s:

```
mgetRedis :: Redis.Connection -> [Text] -> IO [Maybe Text]
mgetRedis connection keys =
    runRedis connection action
    where
        action = do

            result <- Redis.mget $ tbs <$> keys
            -- `result` is of type `Either Reply [Maybe BS.ByteString]`

            case result of
                Right values -> pure $ fmap T.decodeUtf8 <$> values
                      -- equivalent to (fmap . fmap) T.decodeUtf8 $ values
                _            -> pure []
```

The `fmap . fmap` pattern repeats, i.e. you could fmap three levels deep with `fmap . fmap . fmap`. But at that point it would probably be better to just think of the whole stack as a single functor, which can be done by way of *monad transformers*.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not quite at the point of understanding monad transformers just yet, but its's good to learn that this might be a use case for them. Will look into it.